# Create a project in a subfolder in Visual Studio Online (TFS)

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is there any way to create a project in a subfolder in Visual Studio Online using TFVC?

Comment: What kind of project do you mean? TFS project or Visual Studio project that you want to place in a subfolder of the Source Control tree? Have you already tried creating a folder structure in Source Control Explorer?

Comment: If I use the "Create Team Project" dialog in the web based portal then I get asked for Project Name, Description, Process Template and Version Control but it always creates the team project in the root folder of TFS.  I want to have a hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, a TFS Team Project Collection is a flat collection of Team Projects. You cannot organize them in a hierarchy. So you could only depict the hierarchy by naming the Team Projects accordingly.

In a Team Project Source Control tree, you can place many Visual Studio projects and organize them in a folder hierarchy. You can set permissions on specific folders in Version Control if you need to secure some of the projects (though this is not as easy and straightforward as in separate Team Projects).

So maybe it is an alternative to place the projects in a single Team Project and create the hierarchy in source control and areas/iterations. Precondition is are that the projects share the same process; it's also good if they want to share work items or code at least once in a while.

If you want to separate them strictly, you need to create separate Team Projects and do without the hierarchy.